# How to populate dynamic form field values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So in my application user have an option to enter a number, for example if user enters as "5" then it will add 5 textInputs. By this, i have successfully looped the textInput. Now, how to populate or store the values in the state ?

```
My code :

this.state = 
   {
     usersDetails: [{name: "", age: "", gender: "", primary: false}, {name: "", age: "", gender: "", primary: false}]
   };

handleChange(i, e) {
     const { name, value } = e;
      let users = [...this.state.usersDetails];
      users[i] = {...users[i], [name]: value};
      this.setState({ usersDetails });
      console.log(this.state.usersDetails);
   }

 let items = [];
    
   for (let i = 0; i < this.props.maxSeats; i++) {
           items.push(
              <TextInput 
                  placeholder="Enter Name"
                  onChangeText={this.handleChange.bind(this, i)}
                  value={this.state.userDetails}
              />)
            }
```

With the help of stockoverflow i created the handleChange function but it gives error ! How to populate the values and save on the state for dynamic form !

Kindly guide !

Comment: Looks like you're a few steps away from achieving this and you will have to determine how you want to handle the dynamism of the UI you are building. You might want to have some sort of ID that uniquely relates a given TextInput component with their respective state element. So you can keep multiple different state attributes for each TextInput. The state can have a nested object with `keys` that match the `id` of each element.

Comment: Can you show some example please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
handleChange = (value, index,key) => {  
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    usersDetails: prevState.usersDetails.map((val, mapIndex) => {
      if (mapIndex === index) {
        val[key] = value;
        return val;
      }
      return val;
    }),
  }));
};

for (let i = 0; i < this.props.maxSeats; i++) {
  items.push(
    <TextInput
      key={i}
      placeholder="Enter Name"
      onChangeText={(text) => {
        handleChange(text, i,'name'); // here you can pass name,age whatever
      }}
      value={this.state.userDetails[i].name}
    />,
  );
}
```

Comment: am getting undefined is not an object ( evaluating 'target.value')

Comment: ```onChangeText={(e) => {
        handleChange(e, I,'name'); // here you can pass name,age whatever
      }}``` And in this, i got error at "I" so i changed capital "I" to small "i" and now the new error comes !

Comment: Sorry, I thought it is react.js. Now I edited for RN. Could you check now? it will work

Comment: Its working on first textInput , and after that on second one its not working !

Comment: for example, i have rendered 5 textInputs, and its working onf first textInput but when i type on second its not updating the state or its not working !

Comment: the for loop index and userdetails index should be match